# Azure app service - slot app settings with nested resource

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template, that performs resource group deployment. It mainly consist of web apps and key vault. I want to go with blue/green deployment and sometimes need to add only blue slot settings to web app.

When we are deploying web app site all as one resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?tabs=json), it's quite easy as appSettings are being defined as key-values and we can add 3rd key as `"slotSetting": true`.

However, in my scenario, I want to deploy all in Complete mode, in the same time add dynamically key vault access policies. So based on this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#azure-resource-manager-deployment - I need to configure appSettings as separate resource, which is an object, so there's no way to add this additional property.

With this, I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to add this slotSetting when deploying appSettings as separate resource?

Those are little bit off topic but about that case as well:

2. but I'm trying to find a best practise, when it comes to deploying resources + key vault and dynamic access policies. As on complete mode we can't just conditionally not deploy key vault (because it will try to remove it) and on the other hand when we define it, we need to add empty array of `AccessPolicies` (empty because we need to add accessPolicies in separate resources so we could loop over all web apps and get identity), so by and large, the apps are down for some time. Not the best practise when you want to reach **0 downtime deployment**.
3. In what exact scenarios we want to use Complete mode deployment? My team leads are pushing for it but I don't see much added value. If we have ARM template well defined, all manual changes will be changed or moved to defaults in Incremental as well as Complete. Just additional resources are deleted. Do you have any interesting use case to share?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I fully understand your question but when deploying slots you can deploy different app settings to the individual slot in the ARM template simply by specifying them in the slot setting itself when you create it.

You can create the RBAC policies first for the Vault and then apply them to the Vault at creation time but it gets a little complicated, and why dont you just use incremental mode, the only difference is that things not specified wont be deleted.

I have never found a good use case for Complete mode other than dev instances where I can specify a single resource and have it clean up all other things, but in a produciton environment running Complete mode seems to be totally weird